# Google Docs spreadsheet FILTER formula modify on princip MUST contain word BUT NOT word

Tags: google-docs, google-sheets, formula

I am using the following Google Docs formula to display cells content if they contains a specific word or phrase:

=FILTER(Sheet7!B2:B;MMULT(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(" "&G2:G&" ");" "&Sheet7!B2:B&" ");SIGN(ROW(Sheet7!B2:B))))

In one column, in this case I use column G, I have a list of words which a specific cell must contain to be displayed. All works well, but now I wonder if it is possible to modify this formula so I can also add a **list of unwanted words in cells**. I would like to use a princip:

CELL MUST CONTAIN phrase BUT NOT phrase.

For example, if cell contains BLUE SHIRT, than its content should be displayed, but if cell contains BLUE SHOES OR BLUE HAT etc., than content should NOT be displayed.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the phrases to be excluded are in H2:H:

```
=FILTER(Sheet7!B2:B;
        MMULT(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(" "&G2:G&" ");" "&Sheet7!B2:B&" ");SIGN(ROW(G2:G)));
        NOT(MMULT(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(" "&H2:H&" ");" "&Sheet7!B2:B&" ");SIGN(ROW(H2:H))))
       )
```

---

As discussed previously, be careful with the array in the second argument of MMULT. Its vertical length should match the width of the horizontal array in the first argument.

Comment: Once again...thank you AdamL, I really appreciate your answers and knowledge!